# How to handle failed ajax request with promise

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

I am making multiple ajax requests like this

```js
imgPromises = [];

imgPromise1 = $.ajax({
  url: s3Url,
  type: "POST",
  data: s3FormData,
  mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
  contentType: false,
  cache: false,
  processData: false
}).done(function(data, status, formXHR) {
  x = formXHR['responseText'].toString();
  var uploadedUrl = x.match("<Location>(.*)</Location>")[1];
  if ($(this).attr('id').startsWith('inp')) {
    if ($(this).attr('id').startsWith('inp')) $('footer').css('background-image', 'url(' + uploadedUrl + ')');
    footerBackground = $('footer').css('background');
  }
}).fail(function() {
  console.log("in ajax fail");
}.bind(this));

imgPromises.push(imgPromise1);

imgPromise2 = $.ajax({
  url: s3Url,
  type: "POST",
  data: s3FormData,
  mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
  contentType: false,
  cache: false,
  processData: false
}).done(function(data, status, formXHR) {
  x = formXHR['responseText'].toString();
  var uploadedUrl = x.match("<Location>(.*)</Location>")[1];
  if ($(this).attr('id').startsWith('inp')) {
    if ($(this).attr('id').startsWith('inp')) $('footer').css('background-image', 'url(' + uploadedUrl + ')');
    footerBackground = $('footer').css('background');
  }
}).fail(function() {
  console.log("in ajax fail");
}.bind(this));

imgPromises.push(imgPromise2);

Promise.all(imgPromises.then(function() {});
```

If any of the promise(`imgPromise1` or `imgPromise2`) fails then it didn't go to `Promise.all`.

I want that in every case it should go to `Promise.all`.

Comment: [`.catch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) to catch rejected promises, but you have a `Promise.all` with only a single promise, which isn't of much use...

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? You don't need Promise.all since this is not in IE11 but you can use $.when if you're using newer version of jQuery

Answer (score 1):

you are using `then` in the wrong place.

```
const Fail = function(error){this.error=error;};//special Fail type value
const isFail = o=>(o&&o.constructor)===Fail;//see if item passed is fail type
const isNotFail = o => !isFail(o);//see if item passed is not fail type
Promise.all(imgPromises
  .map(
    p=>Promise.resolve(p)/**convert to real promise*/
  ).map(
    p=>p.catch(error=>new Fail(error))//single request failed, resolve with Fail value
  )
)
.then(function (responses) {
  // successes = responses.filter(isNotFail)
  // failed = responses.filter(isFail)
})
.catch(function (err) {
  //handle error
});
```

[MDN page for Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: imgPromises are not real promises and depending on jQuery version you cannot catch and resolve with special value. For example: `Promise.all(imgPromises.map(p=>p.catch(e=>new Fail(e)))).then(always resolves with rejecting promises contain Fail type` This would only work with jQuery version 3 or higher. You could do `Promise.all(imgPromises.map(p=>Promise.resolve(p))...` to convert jQuery deferred to real promise. If you want to support older browsers then you could stick with Deferred of jQuery version 3 or use Promise polyfil and convert jQuery deferred.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of jQuery you are using you can use `.catch` and return something in catch that the promise will resolve with.

jQuery's version of Promise.all ($.when) will not reject if any of the deferred (is jQuery promise implementation) rejects.

This is only since version 3 since jQuery's deferred before this version did not behave like standardized promises (the promises native to modern browsers).

```js
function makeRequest(num){//returning $.Deferred like $.ajax will
  var d = $.Deferred();
  setTimeout(() => {
 if(num>1){//reject if number passed is higher than 1
      d.reject("Rejecting over one");
      return;
    }
  d.resolve(num)
  }, 10);
  return d.promise();
}

$.when.apply(//jQueries Promise.all need apply to pass array of "promises"
  $,
  [1,2].map(//map numbers 1 and 2 to deferred 1 will resolve 2 rejects
    function(num){
      return makeRequest(num)
      .catch(//catch rejected deferred
        function(error){return "error in:"+num; }//resolve with this
      );
    }
  )
).then(//both deferred (=jQuery promise like) are resolved
  function(){
    console.log("it is done",[].slice.apply(arguments));
  }
)
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

However, you try the same with version 2 of jQuery and it won't work because implementation of deferred/promise is not like standard promises in versions lower than 3. You could convert Deferred to real promise but if you want to support older browsers you need [Promise polyfil](https://github.com/lahmatiy/es6-promise-polyfill):

```js
console.log("jQuery version",jQuery.fn.jquery);

function makeRequest(num){//function returning jQuery deferred (could be $.ajax)
  var d = $.Deferred();
  if(num>1){
    //now this will throw an error
    throw("Rejecting over one");
  }
  setTimeout(() => {
    d.resolve(num)
  }, 10);
  return d.promise();
}

Promise.all(
  [1,2].map(
    function(num){
      //convert deferred to real Promise (having catch) if makeRequest throws then promise is rejected
      return Promise.resolve().then(()=>makeRequest(num))
      .catch(
        function(error){return "error in:"+num; }//resolve to error in... string
      );
    }
  )
).then(
  function(){
    console.log("it is done",[].slice.apply(arguments));
  }
)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To wait until all promises finish their tasks (resolve and/or reject) we `return` value of `catch()` for each promise.

In this case we use `.then()` to receive all information.

We can filter both rejected and resolved data using `filterInformation` helper function.

**Example:**

```js
const mockResolvePromise = (message) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve(message)
  })
}
  
const mockRejectPromise = (messageError) => {
  return new Promise((_, reject) => {
    reject(messageError)
  })
}

const ajax0 = mockResolvePromise({ nice: 'data' })
const ajax1 = mockRejectPromise('bad error');
const ajax2 = mockRejectPromise('semi bad error');
const ajax3 = mockRejectPromise('super bad error');
const ajax4 = mockResolvePromise({ hello: 'handsome' })

const promises = [ajax0, ajax1, ajax2, ajax3, ajax4];
// Now lets add catch
const promisesWithCatch = promises.map(p => p.catch(e => { return { error: e } }))
  
  
const filterInformation = (stuff) => {
  return stuff.reduce((prev, current) => {
    
    if (current.error) return { 
      ...prev, 
      errors: [...prev.errors, current.error]
    };
    
    return { ...prev, data: [...prev.data, current] }
  
  }, { errors: [], data: [] })
}
  
  Promise.all(promisesWithCatch)
    .then(filterInformation)
    .then(data => console.log(data))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Note that the OP is using jQuery deferred, options are to use Promise (with polyfil if IE11 needs to be supported) and do `Promise.resolve($.ajax)` so the following will actually work `Promse.all([Promise.resolve($.ajax(...)).catch(resolveWithErrorDescription)])` option 2 would be to use jQuery version 3 and keep using jQuery.Deferred instead of Promise so you can support IE11 and older browsers without polyfill for Promise.